# ubuntu 23.04 kdenlive 23.04

Tags: kdenlive

I installed ubuntu 22.04 a year ago. Until the update in April 2023 it was very fast as a rocket, and after the update it is so slow that I have to push it. Kdenlive 22.04 compiled an mp4 file in 2 hours and an mp3 file in 5 minutes. kdenlive 23.04. not only does it take 2 hours to compile an mp3 file, but it plays the movie very slowly with jumps. what is the reason for this and what is the recipe to get back to the old speed?

Comment: How did you install Kdenlive? Are you using snap? Can you check if switching to flatpak package helps? In case you don't know how to, feel free to reply back

Comment: I first installed kdenlive in April 2022 and then took updates until May 2023 when I stopped accepting it. I installed ubuntu 23.04 on May 10, 2023 from USB, and kdenlive from Ubuntu software. i accept neither ubuntu nor kdenlive.

Comment: I don't understand switching to flatpak package

Comment: kdenlive prior to 23.04 was able to render an mp3 file from a 2 hour mp4 clip for 5 minutes as if it would skip the image completely, and 23.04 doesn't skip the image even if I remove it from the project only the sound alone renders for 2 hours. Why?

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove kdenlive && sudo snap remove kdenlive && sudo apt install flatpak && flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
    && flatpak install flathub org.kde.kdenlive`

Comment: the terminal does not accept characters when I enter the password

Comment: When you enter a password, the terminal does not show anything for security reasons. Simply type your password and press enter